# Get Facebook Likes and Events of non-friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Facebook allows to get list of Likes and Events of a currently authenticated user and his friends by:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes
https://graph.facebook.com/[friend's_user_ID]/likes
```

We need to get list of Likes and Events of people who aren't friends with a currently authenticated user. I tried this to get Likes:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[non-friend's_user_ID]/likes
```

but that only returns the blank response

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

**Is there any way to get Likes and Events of non-friends (those who are not my friends)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user's likes are public you should be able to access them with any access token, but otherwise no.

Comment: I thought the same way. But it seems non-friend should authorize the app that I'm using to access his Likes from. It's really weird, because Privacy Settings explains:  'How people bring your info to apps they use - People who can see your info can bring it with them when they use apps. Use this setting to control the categories of information people can bring with them.'  I see non-friend's public data inside Facebook but it's not accessible through API.

Comment: 1. I logged into my FB account and authorized [FB Devtool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) app and asked my friend to remove me from the list of his friends.  2. I requested his Likes and did get nothing. 3. I asked him to authorize the same app. I got all his Likes after he has done that.